# GIMP: auto resize canvas size to image size

Tags: gimp

I copied a layer from another image file ,  and created a empty canvas to hold the image copied.

But when I create the new canvas , the default size was as same as the original canvas , where I copied this layer.

How can I resize the canvas size to exactly the size of the image I copied ?
As you can see , it's already under selection , maybe there's some way out from here.

Or if anyone knows how to set the canvas size from layer , when you create the empty cavnas , it's a neat solution as well.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Copy the layer then use `shift` + `ctrl` + `v` to create a new image from the copied layer.

Comment: Cool ! +1 for the convenient , exactly what I want

Answer (score 15):

You can use "Crop to Selection" to achieve this.

Make sure the image is selected. Right click anywhere on canvas and navigate to "Image" menu, In image menu select "Crop to Selection".

[image]

Hare's the result!

[image]

Comment: 'Image'->'Autocrop Image' also works.

Answer (score 2):

To fit the copied layer to the canvas size:

1. Right click on the layer
2. Select "Layer to Image Size"

This will scale the layer to the image size